# Differentiable cauchy riemann equation

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

If f is differentiable and |f(z) = 7| in D(0,5) then f(z) is a constant function on this disk D(0,5). Is this true?

Comment: Does $|f(z)=7|$ mean $|f(z)|=7$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's a consequence of the maximum modulus principle: if $f$ is analytic and nonconstant in the interior of a region, then $|f(z)|$ has no maximum value in that interior.

As an alternative: if $f$ is differentiable, and $f'(z_0) \ne 0$, then $f$ "looks like" multiplication by $f'(z_0)$ locally, i.e., 
$$
f(z) \approx f(z_0) + f'(z_0) (z - z_0).
$$
Since multiplication by a nonzero complex number represents a nonsingular map from the plane to itself, this says that $f$ takes a small open disk around $z_0$, to a small elliptical area around $f(z_0)$. In particular, there's a point near $z_0$ sent to a point whose modulus is greater than that of $f(z_0)$. Conclusion: if the derivative of $f$ is nonzero anywhere, then the image of $f$ near that point has nonconstant modulus.